# как сделать, что бы PHPstorm стартовал с окна выбора проекта?

Tags: phpstorm

phpstorm по умолчанию открывает предыдущий проект, в большинстве случаев это хорошо. Но у меня много разных проектов, и хотелось бы иметь возможность выбора.

На данный момент запускаю phpstorm, потом file->close project, и выбираю нужный мне проект над которым сейчас буду работать. Хотелось бы упростить данный пункт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings**, выключите опцию **Reopen last project on startup**